# Cannot redirect to nil! - basic MVC operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

(I'm having some hard time for days to manage to chose a random item
from teh database and to be able to pass it further.)

It is basic operation and i tried several ways all,  brought me to the
same problem,  params {"id" = "random"} <- the name of the controller
method

controller:

```
def random      # method works  checked it in the console. Returns a valid obj.
  @task = Task.find(rand(Task.first.id..Task.last.id))
  render "random"
end
```

random.html.erb
       `<%= @task %>`   # i want it to make it work, if i pass manually
lets #say `../random/1` lets say as an example it works it shows me the
memory #location of the object.

error log:

```
 ActionController::ActionControllerError in TasksController#show
Cannot redirect to nil!

Rails.root: /home/bogdan/ex/bored
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb:60:in
`redirect_to'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/flash.rb:25:in
`redirect_to'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:60:in
`block in redirect_to'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block
in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3)
lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in
`instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:59:in
`redirect_to'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in
`send_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in
`process_action'
.
.
.
(only the top of the stack)

Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"random"}
```

**EDIT**:
Bored::Application.routes.draw do

roots.rb :

```
  to => 'tasks#main'   
  resources :tasks
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

Comment: Your route would help. That's a likely source of the problem.

Comment: And you can test quickly by making @test = Task.first to get one more piece of complexity out of the picture. If that's still broken, as it likely is, I'd bet on your routes being RESTful instead of match

Answer (score 0):

If your route restful and you have a GET on a resource, it expects an ID. If you do GET on the collection its not needed. I'd make sure that random looks something like

```
resources :tasks do
  get 'random', :on => :collection
end
```

Comment: yes tasks it is :P, but i dont have an :collection methiod when indexing... i have `@tasks = Task.find(:all)... hwo should i do this